# Does Selenium WebDriver support Safari?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, safari

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I want to use Safari browser. Does `Selenium WebDriver` support `Safari`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SafariDriver is still experimental and relies on a browser plugin using WebSockets to communicate to the browser. It's a great step and it's something that many have been waiting for.

However, if you want something a bit more stable, Darrel Grainger has a [good post](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-selenium-20-with-webdriver-and.html) on how to instantiate a Webdriver object utilizing the Selenium RC (a.k.a Selenium 1) API.

It's probably the best way to get Safari testing going right now.

Refer latest post here by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari

Comment: It's for Selenium RC (a.k.a Selenium 1). How to use Safari with Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a Selenium 2)?

Answer (score 10):

Experimental support of Safari was added in Selenium recently. See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Comment: The above link does not exist more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, webdriver will support Safari. following instruction https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Comment: I no longer see the Safari Driver listed there.

Comment: The above link does not exist any more.

Answer (score 2):

As of Safari 10, there is now a native support for WebDriver API. More info here https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Selenium Java API doc:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

There are detail of Class SafariDriver

Answer (score 1):

All these answers were out of date for me.  I had to track down and find the latest ... it's located here :

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/69-safari

Download for the driver is

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

**Short and precise answer is YES.**

Selenium 3 supports Safari 12 in a well mannered way. It's pretty much stable for automation testing.

I am using **Selenium v3.141.59** with **Safari v12.1.2** flawlessly.

With Selenium 3, you don't need to download/install SafariDriver explicitly; instead you just need to **enable the built in SafariDriver** comes with MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Web driver does support safari with the help of crome driver.

please see this

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-s-drivers

Comment: Did you try this? When I'm trying to run a test against Safari it only opens a browser window and there is only the message: "SafariDriver requesting connection at ws://localhost:48139/wd". May be you know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support Safari but, it is not much stable as of now!

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite: Install Safari on Windows

1. Go to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Scroll down -> Go to the section "SafariDriver" and download "SafariDriver.safariextz"
3. Double click on "SafariDriver.safariextz" (previously downloaded)
4. Safari would open with a pop up containing "Install" button -> Click Install button
5. Now go to Preferences of Safari and you would see WebDriver (in my case WebDriver 2.48.0) is installed (Enable WebDriver checkbox is checked))
6. Write the WebDriver Java code as below:

   WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-selenium-testing-tools-video");

Answer (score -1):

No. It does not support Safari 2 or 3 with the WebDriver according to the [compatibility page](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html).