# which version of safari driver is compatible with safari version 8.0.7

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

Which version of `safari-driver` is compatible with safari version 8.0.7. After upgrading to safari v8.0.7 browser from safari v7.1.8, when I ran my tests, several safari browser instances open up and my scripts fail. It was working fine before with selenium version 2.45.0 and browser version 7.1.8.

Comment: can you please provide more details on your failures?

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884840/does-selenium-webdriver-support-safari

Answer (score 0):

Selenium version 2.48.0 able to run Safari 8.0.7.